# Shall an active piezo buzzer module draw as much as 10mA on its signal pin?

Tags: current, piezo, buzzer

I have connected an active piezo buzzer to my arduino: [KY-012 Active buzzer module](https://tkkrlab.nl/wiki/Arduino_KY-012_Active_buzzer_module).

I was a bit surprised that it drew like ~10mA on the signal pin from my nodemcu, which I find a bit weird, since the signal generator itself is powered separately. Even if 10mA is in spec of the GPIO pins I wonder if that much current is considered a normal amount to expect.

The module draws an additional ~10mA from the power supply line.

Has probably someone the possibility to provide comparable measurements?

Comment: For what it's worth: https://arduinomodules.info/ky-012-active-buzzer-module/   ... it has 3 pins, but the middle pin is not even connected and the max current is 30 mA (which is within absolute max current limits of an Arduino GPIO but not 'recommended'.

Comment: The middle pin must be connected somehow. It draws a current, when the `S` pin is connected to VCC. But it is correct, that even when unconnected, the module produces a sound.... weird.